# Pycharm to show current working branch name

Tags: git, pycharm

When viewing VCS window in Pycharm IDE, I have no idea what *git local branch* I'm working on as well as its mapped *git remote branch*.

So how to show **current working branch name** in Pycharm?

p.s.

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2

Comment: Do you see the current branch at the bottom right of the Pycharm window ?

Comment: Yeah I can see that; though the mapped on remote is not there...

Comment: I'd like to add that this does not work very well if you have multiple attached projects. The bottom right shows the branch for the first (top) project, but I still don't know what branch I am on for the other projects.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Local Working Branch

The section "[Which branch we are working in?](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Using+PyCharm%27s+Git+integration+locally#UsingPyCharm%27sGitintegrationlocally-Whichbranchweareworkingin?)" is quite clear:

> Actually, this information is available in the Logs tab, but there are two another ways to see the current branch.
>
> First, there is a special command on the main menu VCS→Git→Branches. The pop-up window of existing branches appears

[image: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/51959419/git6.png?version=1&modificationDate=1377102558000&api=v2]

> Second (and most handy) is to use the **Git widget in the Status bar**:

[image]

## Remote mapped branch

The remote tracking branch though, does not seem to be displayed, except when you are pushing the branch via menu *VCS - Git - Push*

[image: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mastering-pycharm/9781783551316/graphics/1316_09_07.jpg]

For that, a `git branch -avv` in command line remains the most complete source of information.

Comment: Lovely answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'd argue that it needs to be more obvious.  Inadvertently making changes to the wrong branch could create a nightmare.  Anyone know if there's an option to make it stand out more?

Comment: @elPastor I agree, and 2 years later, I am not aware of such an option.

Comment: Git widget in the Status bar is very clear! How could I never noticed it and dying to find out which branch I am on!

Answer (score 10):

A small update to the wonderful answer by @VonC: there is an option to show the git branch in the git widget in the bottom of the screen. It's called `Show Git Branch` and you can turn it on either using the command lookup or from `View > Appearance > Status Bar Widgets > Git Branch`.
[image]